# Sticky nav bar implementation failed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using some code from a codepen project to work on a sticky sidebar with purejs. When the height of the sidebar is increased to 100vh in the css from my own project, the sidebar functionality stops, even though it is the same code as in the Pen. Could someone give a brief explanation of the code?

This is the code:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
  main = document.getElementById("main"),
  sidebar = document.getElementById("sc");
window.onscroll = function() {
  document.getElementById('sc').setAttribute("style", "display:block;width:" + document.getElementById("sidebar").offsetWidth + "px");
  document.getElementById('sc').style.width = document.getElementById("sidebar").offsetWidth;
  //if sidebar smaller than main
  if (sidebar.offsetHeight < main.offsetHeight) {
    //if sidebar smaller than screen - stick to top rather than bottom
    if (sidebar.offsetHeight < window.innerHeight) {
      if ((wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < (window.innerHeight)) &&
        ((wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < sidebar.offsetHeight))
      ) {
        wrapper.classList.remove("fix-top-VP");
        wrapper.classList.add("flex-bottom");
      } else if (wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0) {
        wrapper.classList.add("fix-top-VP");
        wrapper.classList.remove("flex-bottom");
      } else {
        wrapper.classList.remove("fix-top-VP");
        wrapper.classList.remove("flex-bottom");
      }
    }
    //if wrapper taller than sidebar - stick to bottom
    else if (sidebar.offsetHeight < wrapper.offsetHeight) {
      if (wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < (window.innerHeight)) {
        wrapper.classList.remove("fix-bottom-VP");
        wrapper.classList.add("flex-bottom");
      } else if (wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > (sidebar.offsetHeight + window.innerHeight)) {
        wrapper.classList.remove("fix-bottom-VP");
        wrapper.classList.remove("flex-bottom");
      } else {
        wrapper.classList.add("fix-bottom-VP");
        wrapper.classList.remove("flex-bottom");
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header,
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
}

body,
#main,
#wrapper,
#sc {
  padding: 15px;
}

#main {
  background-color: #F88300;
  width: 60%;
  height: 180vh;
}

#sidebar {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
}

#sc {
  background-color: #FFD600;
  height: 80vh;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#wrapper.fix-bottom-VP #sc,
#wrapper.fix-top-VP #sc {
  position: fixed;
}

#wrapper.fix-bottom-VP #sc {
  bottom: 15px;
}

#wrapper.fix-top-VP #sc {
  top: 15px;
}

#wrapper.flex-bottom {
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Lightweight, Intelligent Sticky Sidebar, NO libraries</h1>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="main">
    Main content
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sc">
      Sticky sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Jeyjoo/pen/YOQxBx)

I am open to a better implementation of the same idea there.

Comment: Can't you make use of: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Comment: Hi Mark, did one of the answers below solve your problem? If so, please accept one of them using the green check mark. It lets the answerers know that your problem has been solved. If not, please expand on what problems you are continuing to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by updating your JavaScript with the following code

```
  var header = document.getElementById("header"),
        sticky = header.offsetTop,
        wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"), 
        main = document.getElementById("main"), 
        sidebar = document.getElementById("sc");

    window.onscroll = function() {

        if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
          header.classList.add("sticky");
        } else {
          header.classList.remove("sticky");
        }

      document.getElementById('sc').setAttribute("style","display:block;width:" + document.getElementById("sidebar").offsetWidth+"px");
      document.getElementById('sc').style.width = document.getElementById("sidebar").offsetWidth; 

      
      //if sidebar smaller than main
      if (sidebar.offsetHeight < main.offsetHeight) {
        //if sidebar smaller than screen - stick to top rather than bottom
        if (sidebar.offsetHeight < window.innerHeight) {
          if ((wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < (window.innerHeight))
              && ((wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < sidebar.offsetHeight))
             ) {
            wrapper.classList.remove("fix-top-VP");
            wrapper.classList.add("flex-bottom");
          }
          else if (wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0 ) {
            wrapper.classList.add("fix-top-VP");
            wrapper.classList.remove("flex-bottom");
          }
          else {
            wrapper.classList.remove("fix-top-VP");
            wrapper.classList.remove("flex-bottom");
          }
        }
        //if wrapper taller than sidebar - stick to bottom
        else if (sidebar.offsetHeight < wrapper.offsetHeight) {
          if (wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom < (window.innerHeight)) {
            wrapper.classList.remove("fix-bottom-VP");
            wrapper.classList.add("flex-bottom");
          }
          else if (wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > (sidebar.offsetHeight + window.innerHeight)) {
            wrapper.classList.remove("fix-bottom-VP");
            wrapper.classList.remove("flex-bottom");
          }
          else {
            wrapper.classList.add("fix-bottom-VP");
            wrapper.classList.remove("flex-bottom");
          }
        }
      }
}
```

and and to your CSS  the following code

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position:sticky` and html5 elements such as `header`, `footer`, `main` and `aside`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #369;
  color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

header, footer, main, aside {
  padding: 15px;
}

main, aside {
  font-size: 20px;
}

main {
  background-color: #ed3;
  height: 180vh;
  flex-grow: 3;
}

aside {
  background-color: #fe5;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Sticky Sidebar - best practice</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="flex-row">
    <main>
      Main content
    </main>
    <aside>
      Sticky sidebar
    </aside>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </footer>
</body>
```